# Is a reversible distribution unique?

Tags: stochastic-processes

For a time-homogeneous discrete time Markov chain, 
a reversible distribution of the chain is defined as $\pi$ that satisfies:
$$
    π_i p_{ij} = π_j p_{ji}, \forall i, j.
$$

I was wondering if a reversible distribution is unique when exists?

Thanks!

Comment: No. Check some simple cases.

Comment: @did: Thanks! When the states are all isolated, $p_{ij}$ are all zero, so any distribution can be reversible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to did! When the states are all isolated, $p_{ij}$ are all zero for $i \neq j$, so any distribution can be reversible.